# Rails5 + ActionCable: WebSocket connection to 'ws://{hostname}/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, actioncable

I get `WebSocket connection to 'ws://{hostname}/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.` in my chrome browser when connecting to my Rails 5 + ActionCable app. In my local development environment, it doesn't happen. It only happens in my staging and production environment.

[Successful screenshot on development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWQqM.png)

[Failed screenshot on staging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRUMn.png)

I use Amazon ElasticBeanstalk to deploy my app. After monitoring requests with chrome developer tool, I figured out that unlike development environment, WebSocket request in staging, production environment doesn't get response(pending) so ActionCable constantly tries to connect to the WebSocket endpoint (ws://{hostname}/cable).

The thing is, in my puma.log, it says something like this:

```
I, [2016-07-26T13:45:53.921154 #32369]  INFO -- : Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vYXNrLWNvLWRlL1VzZXIvMg)
I, [2016-07-26T13:46:05.775788 #32369]  INFO -- : Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 121.166.105.106 at 2016-07-26 13:46:05 +0000
I, [2016-07-26T13:46:18.074895 #32369]  INFO -- : [917fd706-4f1a-4178-bd95-7a33c0c7b621] Started GET "/cable" for 121.166.105.106 at 2016-07-26 13:46:18 +0000
I, [2016-07-26T13:46:18.075764 #32369]  INFO -- : [917fd706-4f1a-4178-bd95-7a33c0c7b621] Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 121.166.105.106 at 2016-07-26 13:46:18 +0000
I, [2016-07-26T13:46:18.075817 #32369]  INFO -- : [917fd706-4f1a-4178-bd95-7a33c0c7b621] Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
```

that is, upgrade to WebSocket was successful but the rest is unknown. Do you have any clue on resolving this?

Comment: I resolved this issue by removing load balancing from Elastic Beanstalk, that is, by creating a new environment without auto scaling. I guess there was some problem regarding HTTP header while load balancing.

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: could you elaborate? are you on AWS?

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution for this problem with Load Balancer in place?

Answer (score 0):

As the author of the question already commented the probable cause of this failure in the websocket connection was due to a request rewrite when behind a mis-configured Loadbalancer.

I for example encountered a mis-configured Apache Server where the rewrite rules were in place to rewrite the used protocol from http to ws for a rails application.

In case it helps others here is the working Apache VHost config that enabled websockets in that case.

```
<VirtualHost domain.of.the.rails-app:80>
    ServerName domain.of.the.rails-app
    DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/rails-app/public
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /error-documents !
    ErrorDocument 503 /error-documents/503.html
    Alias /error-documents /var/www/apps/rails-app/public
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```